# How can I remove a specific developer identity from my system when creating Flutter projects?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, apple-id

I have previously added a developer identity for `"Apple Development: Tanisha Bagamane (GHT9MB2GT4)"` to my Mac in order to push an app for a client project to the Apple Store. However, I now want to create new Flutter projects without this identity being selected by default.

When I try to create a new Flutter project from the terminal, it automatically selects `"Apple Development: Tanisha Bagamane (GHT9MB2GT4)"` as the developer identity for iOS deployment.

[image]

I would like to know how I can remove this specific developer identity from my system so that it no longer appears as an option when creating new Flutter projects.

I have already tried looking for a solution online, but I have not been able to find a clear answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this problem. here is how i did

- Open the Keychain Access application on your Mac.
- In the top bar, select "My Certificates".

[image]

- Locate the certificate for "Apple Development: Tanisha Bagamane (GHT9MB2GT4)" and select it.
- Right-click on the certificate and select "Delete".
- Confirm that you want to delete the certificate by clicking "Delete" again.
  This should remove the developer identity for "Apple Development: developer id name (in my case Tanisha Bagamane)" from your system, and you should no longer see it when creating new Flutter projects.

Note: If you need to use this developer identity again in the future, you will need to import it back into Keychain Access.

Comment: If  I have previously added a developer identity can i able to change or not in feature any problem will occured